# Which syntax is more correct?

Tags: java, syntax, format

```
if (conditionA && conditionB) { return true; }

if (conditionA && !conditionB) { return false;}
```

** OR **

```
if (conditionA) { 
    if (conditionB) { 
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

---

Can provide more context if necessary? Is it different accross the different languages? Is it all the same?

Comment: Across which different languages? Is your question about Java?

Comment: Please, can you provide more context?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest:

```
if (condition A) {
    return conditionB;
}
```

My reasons are as follows:

- repeating the `if (conditionA` violates the "don't repeat yourself" principle. If you change it in one place you need to change it in both
- `if (condition) return true else return false;` seems to be unnecessarily complex when the intent is to just return the value of the second value.
- In general it seems to perfectly capture your intent: if conditionA is true the return true or false depending on conditionB

Comment: Why would you suggest this?

Comment: I'll add the reasons to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
return conditionA && conditionB;
```

Comment: This is incorrect, because the OP's code doesn't return if `conditionA` is false.

Comment: @DavidWallace, this is correct

Comment: Well, it does something different from what the OP's code does, so if this is a correct answer, then it's a correct answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, all are logically same.

If this is in Java, you can further shorten them into `return conditionA && conditionB`

Comment: This is incorrect, because the OP's code doesn't return if `conditionA` is false.

Comment: @DavidWallace, He should correct it. If there is a return statement, it should cover all the posibilities.

Comment: Maybe this is in the middle of a method which _shouldn't_ return if `conditionA` is false.  You've written code which does something quite different from what OP has asked for.

Comment: @DavidWallace Then, you can't say this is incorrect.! Let's leave it for OP to decide

Comment: Well, it's not a correct answer to this question.

Comment: Let's leave it for OP to decide

Answer (score 0):

One golden rule I follow is to **Avoid Nesting** as much as I can. But if it is at the cost of making my single if condition too complex, I don't mind nesting it out.

Besides you're using the short-circuit && operator. So if the boolean is false, it won't even try matching!

In this case, you should look at your code in two parts.

First, check the first condition. If this condition is true, then you need to make another decision based on conditionB.

Therefore, the latter is the better option, although I would refactor as follows:

```
if (conditionA) { 
    return conditionB;
}
```

Comment: can you please bring any source to back you up regarding avoid nesting ? so I can vote u up

Comment: I didn't follow a source, this is just a rule I follow. I think it's cleaner, easier to maintain and understand by avoiding nested statements, although there are many cases where it is necessary to use nested if statements. This is simply a personal preference since most compilers will optimize it anyway.

Comment: Currently the best answer here,  because it's correct, and because it gives a coherent justification for writing it the way it's been written.

Answer (score 0):

all conditions are same

take this one...

```
if (conditionA && conditionB) { return true; }
```

compiler checkout the other condition only and only if the first one is true.

so no matter which condition you use. compiler optimize it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

lets compare

```
if (conditionA && conditionB) { return true; }

if (conditionA && !conditionB) { return false;}
```

**VS**

```
if (conditionA) { 
    if (conditionB) { 
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

performance wise 1st code is poor because if first condition of if **if (conditionA && conditionB)** wents wrong the compiler will check 2nd condition which is **if (conditionA && !conditionB)**

while in 2nd code **if (conditionA)** wents wrong the compiler will not have any other condition to be checked so the output of both will be same in each conditions but performance would be different

in all of these conditions it is necessary that `conditionA` must be true if `conditionA` is false in any case then i dont think it is required to check condition b and if `conditionA` is `true` and `conditionB` is true then `true` is returned and `false` is returned in case if `conditionB` is false so you can also write it as

```
if(conditionA){
    conditionB
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**(1) Syntax**

```
if (conditionA && conditionB) { return true; }

if (conditionA && !conditionB) { return false;}
```

**(2) Syntax**

```
if (conditionA) { 

    //Only conditionA is true you can write more code and other logic here
    if (conditionB) { 
        return true;
    } 
    //conditionB is true or false, you can write more code and other logic here
    return false;
}
```

Acutally these 2 Syntaxs are not same. 
As to your title question, there has no point to decide Which syntax is more correct from syntaxs same point?

So, according to these differences, you should choose which syntax is meet your logic.

Your logic might be answer for which syntax is more correct.